# Ignite UI series not displaying higher values

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, igdatachart

I am using the Ignite UI igDataChart. The y axis of the series is not displaying the entire height of the columns which have larger values. As indicated by the image, any value over 7 is being cut off. Of the columns in the middle, 3 have values larger than 7. The other 2 = 7. The highlighted column on the right has a value of 44 as indicated by the tool tip, so the chart knows the values, it just isn't drawing the column correctly. I haven't been able to find a configuration setting to control this. Does anyone have any ideas what I need to change?

Here is the configuration object :

```
$("#CurrentInShopChart").igDataChart({
    width: "50%",
    height: "600px",
    title: "Trucks in shop",
    subtitle: "Number of trucks currently in shop by facility",
    dataSource: chartData,
    axes: [
        {
            name: "FacilitiesAxis",
            type: "categoryX",
            title: "Facility",
            label: "FACILITY",
            labelAngle: -90,
            interval: 1
        },
        {
            name: "NumInShopAxis",
            type: "numericY",
            minimumValue: 0,
            title: "Number of trucks in shop",
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            showTooltip: true,
            name: "Trucks",
            type: "column",
            isHighlightingEnabled: true,
            isTransitionInEnabled: true,
            xAxis: "FacilitiesAxis",
            yAxis: "NumInShopAxis",
            valueMemberPath: "NUMINSHOP"

        }
    ]
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by casting the value sent into the chart to a number - Number(value).
The Ignite UI chart logic didn't like the fact that the values were string representations of numbers.

Comment: How did you did that? Did you use some kind of function of infragistics?

Comment: No, just used the javascript built in number function. - Number(x)